# Problem in accessing list (Google Apps) on google homepage with selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Whenever I'm using this code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='gbwa']/div[1]/a")).click();
```

its navigating to "products" page. but I want the dropdown list in the homepage itself to select youtube. I have also tried that process:

```
List<WebElement> li=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".gb_ia"));
WebElement r=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#gb36 > span.gb_3"));
for(WebElement option:li){
    if(option.equals(r)){
        option.click();
        break;
    }
}
```

Its also not working. 
Help plz...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should do the trick:

```
driver.get("http://www.google.com");

WebElement apps = new WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("gbwa")));
apps.click();

WebElement youtube = new WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[.='YouTube']")));
youtube.click();
```

Note that the wait statements can be crucial, as otherwise the tests may fail depending on page load times, network connection, or other reasons that are not within your control.

Comment: No, its not working...its again navigating to "google products" before opening the list where we can find 'youtube' button...so after executing apps.click(); , its showing org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException

Comment: Which browser/operating system/WebDriver version are you running this on? For me (Chrome 56, Win10, Selenium 3.0.1) that works perfectly fine.

Comment: i was using(Firefox 45.03 dev edition, Win10, Selenium 3.0.1)....now just checked in chrome 56....its working fine! Thanks for your kind help....btw, do you have any idea why it was not working in firefox?

Comment: You're right - in Firefox, the first `click` doesn't actually open the "Apps" menu, hence the second `find` times out. This seems to be because the "Apps" button only handles the `click` if the mouse is currently over it. Chrome seems to be simulating that better than Firefox. (You can validate that by stepping through the test in the debugger and moving the mouse over the Apps button before executing the line with the click, and you'll see that the click actually works then.)

Answer (score 1):

This should work even in firefox:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.click(driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@id='gbwa']/div[1]/a")).build().perform();
```

Below will click the **news** links in apps menu.

```
driver.findElementByXPath("//div[@id='gbwa']/div[2]/ul[1]/li[6]/a").click();
```